# Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Job will exceed the maximum amount of Event Hub Receivers

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to write a query in ASA ( Azure Stream Analytics) with lot of left joins. And it is failing to start the job with the following error:

Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Job will exceed the maximum amount of Event Hub Receivers.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely hitting Event Hub's 5 readers limit. Take a look at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-inputs/).

Here is the relevant part:

> **Consumer groups**
>
> ... When a job contains a self-join or multiple inputs, some input may be
>   read by more than one reader downstream, which impacts the number of
>   readers in a single consumer group. To avoid exceeding Event Hub limit of
>   5 readers per consumer group per partition, it is a best practice
>   to designate a consumer group for each Stream Analytics job.
>   ...